# Replacing tokenized string with given object or default value

Tags: java, string, parsing, split

Being new to java and regex I am struggling to find a solution for below problem.

```
   Object obj = new Object();
   String FLTNUM = obj.getFlightNumber(); //1234
   String REGNUM = obj.getRegistration(); //REG111
```

`<TOKEN RW=J>%FLTNUM</TOKEN>_320_Y_<TOKEN RW=N12345>%REGNUM</TOKEN>B6`
(An xml (ish) string.)

In above string I have a requirement as follows:
if FLTNUM is present in object, replace it with flight number else with xml attribute value default ie J
Similarly if REGNUM is present in object, replace with object value else xml attribute value default ie N12345

So final output will be something like:
J_320_Y_N12345B6
OR
1234_320_Y_REG111B6

***************Messy solution I can come up with******************

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        String s = "<TOKEN RW=J>%FLTNUM</TOKEN>_320_Y_<TOKEN RW=N12345>%REGNUM</TOKEN>B6"; // An xml (ish) string.
        String[] split = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(s, "</TOKEN>");
        boolean withDefaultValue = true; // Not passing object, just having a flag to check if value is present or not
        
        List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(split);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(String reg: asList) {
            if(StringUtils.contains(reg, "TOKEN")) {
                 String[] split1 = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(reg, "<TOKEN RW=");
                 List<String> asList2 = Arrays.asList(split1);
                 for(String reqInt: asList2) {
                     if(StringUtils.contains(reqInt, ">")) {
                         String[] split2 = reqInt.split(">");
                         String defaultValue = split2[0];
                         String token = getTokenValue(split2[1]);
                         if(!withDefaultValue && StringUtils.isNotBlank(token)) {
                             builder.append(token); 
                         } else {
                             builder.append(defaultValue);
                         }
                     } else {
                         builder.append(reqInt);
                     }
                 }
            } else {
                builder.append(reg);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
        
    }

    private static String getTokenValue(String token) {
        if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("%FLTNUM", token)) {
            return "1234";
        } else if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("%REGNUM", token)) {
            return "REG12345";
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Above program does give the desired output, however I find it:

- Tooooo cumbersome to maintain and unit test
- Tech debt seems bit high
- Not generic enough to handle all usecases.

Looking for a better solution/guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     String s = "<TOKEN RW=J>%FLTNUM</TOKEN>_320_Y_<TOKEN RW=N12345>%REGNUM</TOKEN>B6";
     System.out.println(process(s));
     s = "<TOKEN RW=J>1234</TOKEN>_320_Y_<TOKEN RW=N12345>REG111</TOKEN>B6";
     System.out.println(process(s));
}   

public static String process(String s) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<TOKEN RW=)(.*?)(>)(.*?)(</TOKEN>)(.*?)(<TOKEN RW=)(.*?)(>)(.*?)(</TOKEN>)(.*)");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
     String output = "";
     if(m.find()) {
         output += m.group(4).contains("FLTNUM") ? "J" : m.group(4);
         output += m.group(6);
         output += m.group(10).contains("REGNUM") ? "N12345" : m.group(10);
         output += m.group(12);
     }
     return output;
}
```

Output:

```
J_320_Y_N12345B6
1234_320_Y_REG111B6
```

Change the pattern as per your needs. Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Thanks a ton @Onkar, this is what I was looking for. Appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: Hey, I did however my up vote is not being recorded since I don't fullfill the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.